# How to achieve Zoom in Zoom out on button click in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullscreen

When you we click in button page should be show in fullscreen, and when again click on same button, page should show in normal mode.

**Actully i want same feature as in Adobe Indesign Zoom feature**.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also don't get your hopes up about the code, **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive that using custom css class, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#maximize').on('click', function(){
    $('#container').toggleClass('fullscreen');
})
```

```css
    .fullscreen{
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    div{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <button id='maximize'>[M]</button>
</div>
```